# Merging different arrays into another one

Tags: ios, arrays, swift

```
struct Product {
    let id: String
    let quantity: Int
    let price: Double
}

class ProductPrices {

    internal static var PricesArray : [String:Double] = ["product1": 5.00,"product2": 5.00,"product3": 5.00]

}

class ProductNames {

    internal static var NamesArray : [String:String] = ["product1": "name1","product2": "name2","product3": "name3"]

}
```

I have this array

```
["product1","product1","product2,"product1","product3","product2"]
```

My question is how can I put these items into `Product`

Expected Result:

```
Product(id: "name1", quantity: 3, price: 15.00)
Product(id: "name2", quantity: 2, price: 10.00)
Product(id: "name3", quantity: 1, price: 5.00)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### The input

So we have a struct

```
struct Product {
    let id: String
    let quantity: Int
    let price: Double
}
```

We also have 2 dictionaries and 1 array

```
let prices = ["product1": 5.00, "product2": 5.00, "product3": 5.00]
let names = ["product1": "name1","product2": "name2","product3": "name3"]
let elms = ["product1", "product1", "product2", "product1", "product3", "product2"]
```

### The output

Now we want to build an array of `Product(s)` using the following logic

1. `Product.id` is retrieved from `names`
2. `Product.quantity` is the number of occurrences of `Product.id` into `elms`
3. `Product.price` is the price of the product * the `quantity`

We can achieve that writing this

```
let products = names.compactMap { elm -> Product? in
    let name = elm.value
    let id = name
    let quantity = elms.filter { $0 == elm.key }.count
    guard quantity > 0, let price = prices[elm.key] else { return nil }
    return Product(id: id, quantity: quantity, price: price * Double(quantity))
}
```

### Test

```
[
    Product(id: "name2", quantity: 2, price: 10.0),
    Product(id: "name1", quantity: 3, price: 15.0),
    Product(id: "name3", quantity: 1, price: 5.0)
]
```

> The `compactMap` method is available in Swift 4.1. For previous versions of Swift please use `flatMap`.

Comment: Actually we have only one array (`elms`) and two dictionaries (`prices`, `names`)... ;)

Comment: @AndréSlotta That's true! Thanks

Comment: I am getting "Value of type '[String]' has no member 'key'" for elm.key part. why would it be?

Comment: @UtkuDalmaz I suspect you made a typo. Are you sure you have written `elm.key` and NOT `elms.key`?

Comment: Oops I am sorry my bad : )

Comment: I have a problem. If array is ["product1"] I am also having others in result array. How to prevent it? @LucaAngeletti

Comment: @UtkuDalmaz I updated my code to include this new requirement

Comment: @LucaAngeletti Amazing! Thank you

Comment: @LucaAngeletti I am sorry for the late request but I also want to add elms array elements to the result array. Can you please also show me how to do that?

Answer (score 0):

Although I am confused about your data structures I show you my approach.
I am sure there are more elegant solutions but it works as expected:

```
let productArray = ["product1", "product1", "product2", "product1", "product3", "product2"]

// create products
var products: [Product] = []
for uniqueProductName in Set(productArray) {
    let quantity = productArray.filter({$0 == uniqueProductName}).count
    guard let id = ProductNames.NamesArray[uniqueProductName],
        let price = ProductPrices.PricesArray[uniqueProductName] else { continue }
    let total = price * Double(quantity)

    let product = Product(id: id, quantity: quantity, price: total)
    products.append(product)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Another solution could be

```
let products = ["product1","product1","product2","product1","product3","product2"]
let (prices, names) = (ProductPrices.PricesArray, ProductNames.NamesArray)

let quantities = products.reduce(into: [:]) { result, product in
    result[product, default: 0] += 1
}

// quantities: ["product2": 2, "product1": 3, "product3": 1]

let result: [Product] =  names.keys.flatMap { key in
    guard let name = names[key],
        let price = prices[key],
        let quantity = quantities[key] else {
            return nil
    }
    return Product(id: name, quantity: quantity, price: price)
}
```